# Using Dependency Injection in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I need use dependency injection in Blazor WebAssembly app. But there is a situation, my blazor app in `UI layer`. I will inject dependency from `business layer` and I need inject `data layer` too. But `UI layer` shouldn't access to data layer. How I can fix this? And another question is, can I adapt Ninject in this Program.cs file?

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyBusiness, MyBusiness>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your business layer in the WebAsm app? That would be strange. The DataLayer can't be in WebAsm, so this question shouldn't even come up. What does MyRepository depend on?

Comment: No. Repositories in DataLayer. Only business layer referenced to WebAsm app. But if I resolve my business layer object in WebAsm, there is error. Because WebAsm want resolve IRepository too. But WebAsm should NOT access to Data layer.

Comment: You need an API. Create a new project from the WebAsm+Hosted template and look at the WeatherForecast.

Comment: I guess you are right. This can be fix that issue.